# Boolean value being changed to true in while loop? C++

Tags: c++, loops, linked-list, conditional-statements, nodes

I have a deck of cards in a singlly linked list. I am trying to randomly swap the values without duplicates. To do this, I have added a boolean variable "used" to each node and set it to false. Whenever I use the cards, I update it to true so they are not used again. I am trying to add a while loop to ensure no used cards are swapped. However, once I start the while loop, every node's used variable becomes set to true, so the while loop is never broken. I have printed the used variable values before the while loop and they are all set to false. Any help is appreciated.

```
 void DeckOfCards::randomSwap()
{
    Card* ptr = head; 
    Card* n = NULL;
    Card* temp = NULL;
    srand((unsigned)(time(0)));

    for (int i = 1; i < 52; ++i)
    {
        
        int r = rand() % 52 + 1;
        n = getNode(r);

        while(n->used != false)
        {
            r = rand() % 52 + 1;
            n = getNode(r);
        }

        temp = ptr;
        ptr->setRank(n->getRank());
        ptr->setSuit(n->getSuit());
        n->setRank(temp->getRank());
        n->setSuit(temp->getSuit());
        n->used = true;
        ptr->used = true;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    std::cout << "Cards randomly swapped." << std::endl;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Card
{
private:
    int cardRank;
    std::string cardSuit;
public: 
    Card* next;
    bool used = false;

    Card();
    ~Card();
    void setRank(int);
    void setSuit(std::string);
    int getRank(); 
    std::string getSuit();

};
```

```
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card()
{
    cardRank = 0; 
    cardSuit = "Default"; 
    next = NULL;
    used = false;
}

Card::~Card()
{
    next = NULL; 
    delete next; 
}

void Card::setRank(int r)
{
    cardRank = r; 
}

void Card::setSuit(std::string s)
{
    cardSuit = s;
}

int Card::getRank()
{
    return cardRank;
}

std::string Card::getSuit()
{
    return cardSuit; 
}
```

```
#include "DeckOfCards.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
{
    head = NULL; 
    tail = NULL;
}

DeckOfCards::~DeckOfCards()
{
    head = NULL; 
    delete head; 
    tail = NULL; 
    delete tail; 
}

void DeckOfCards::addNode(int r, std::string s)
{
    Card* n = new Card; 
    n->setRank(r); 
    n->setSuit(s);
    n->used = false;
    n->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = n; 
        tail = n; 
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = n; 
        tail = tail->next; 
    }
}

void DeckOfCards::createDeck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
        {
            addNode(rank[j], suit[i]);
        }
    }
}

void DeckOfCards::print()
{
    Card* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << temp->getRank() << " of " << temp->getSuit() << ")\n";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}

bool DeckOfCards::CardExists(int r, std::string s)
{
    Card* temp = head; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
    {
        if (r == temp->getRank() && s == temp->getSuit())
            return true; 
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

Card* DeckOfCards::getNode(int pos)
{
    Card* temp = head; 
    for (int i = 0; i < pos-1; ++i)
    {
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
    return temp; 

}

void DeckOfCards::randomSwap()
{
    Card* ptr = head; 
    Card* n = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i < 52; ++i)
    {
        
        int r = rand() % 52 + 1;
        n = getNode(r);

        while(n->used != false)
        {
            std::cout << r << " " << n->used << std::endl;
            r = rand() % 52 + 1;
            n = getNode(r);
        }

        int tempRank = ptr->getRank();
        std::string tempSuit = ptr->getSuit();
    
        ptr->setRank(n->getRank());
        ptr->setSuit(n->getSuit());
        n->setRank(tempRank);
        n->setSuit(tempSuit);

        n->used = true;
        ptr->used = true;

        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    std::cout << "Cards randomly swapped." << std::endl;
}

void DeckOfCards::shuffleCards()
{
    Card* tail = NULL;
    Card* temp = NULL;
    Card* ptr = head;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        tail = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    ptr = head;
    temp = tail;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        int tempRank = temp->getRank();
        std::string tempSuit = temp->getSuit();

        temp->setSuit(ptr->getSuit());
        temp->setRank(ptr->getRank());

        ptr->setSuit(tempSuit);
        ptr->setRank(tempRank);

        temp = getNode(51-i);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    std::cout << "Cards shuffled.\n" << std::endl;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>

class DeckOfCards
{
private: 
    Card *head, *tail; 
    int rank[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    std::string suit[4] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

public: 

    DeckOfCards();
    ~DeckOfCards();
    void addNode(int,std::string);
    void createDeck(); 
    void randomSwap();
    void print();
    void shuffleCards();
    Card* getNode(int);
    bool CardExists(int r, std::string s);


};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DeckOfCards.h"    
#include "CircularList.h"
#include <ctime>
int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)(time(0)));

    DeckOfCards d; 
    d.createDeck(); 
    d.randomSwap();
    d.shuffleCards();

    return 0;
```

Comment: I'm thinking that for a [mre], you could drop the swap and just set `used` on the nodes. At that point, you could drop the rank and suit from `Card`. At that point, you could probably drop your list to, say, five elements to make it easier to see what is going on via a debugger. (This is not for your final code; it's to help isolate the problem.)

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

```
    temp = ptr;
```

Okay, so `temp` and `ptr` are both pointers to the same object.

```
    ptr->setRank(n->getRank());
    ptr->setSuit(n->getSuit());
```

Now, both the object `temp` and `ptr` point to and the object `n` points to have the same rank and suit.

```
    n->setRank(temp->getRank());
    n->setSuit(temp->getSuit());
```

Oops, Now you set the object `n` points to back to the same rank and suit it was in the first place. That wasn't what you wanted to do.

You must be thinking that `ptr->setRank` and `temp->SetRank` do different things. But they do the same thing since they both call `setRank` on the same object. So `temp` serves no purpose here. You need a temporary object or something else temporary that can hold the rank and suit during the swap operation. A temporary pointer doesn't help you.

Also:

```
Card::~Card()
{
    next = NULL; 
    delete next; 
}
```

This does nothing. Setting `next` to `NULL` does nothing because the object is about to stop existing. Calling `delete` on `NULL` does nothing. So what is the purpose of this destructor?

Comment: You try to set *two* cards to used 51 times. That won't work with only 52 cards. Also, your destructor for `DeckOfCards` does nothing. There's no point in setting the values of members of an object that's about to not exist and there's no point in intentionally passing `NULL` to `delete`.

Comment: @ZachSal first year CS student?  All the more reason to build up your debugging skills.  If you have to go running to StackOverflow every time something doesn't work, it's going to be very frustrating for you.  And frustrating for us too.  The closer you can come to solving a problem on your own, the better quality of help you will receive.